# Postgres - How to cast varchar to time with just minutes and seconds?

Tags: sql, postgresql, time, casting

I have a column that has data in the format of `MI:SS`. I need to convert this to a `TIME` data type, but when trying to cast to `TIME` I get the following error:

```
select column_time::time
```

> date/time field value out of range: "29:51"

It seems to be expecting the format of HH:MI, so the 29 is out of the range and causing the issue. How can I work around this?

Edit: found this works, but it has leading 00's for hours which I thought weren't there before.

```
TO_TIMESTAMP(column_time, 'MI:SS')::time
```

Answer (score 6):

There is a subtle difference between a cast and the function call `to_timestamp()` - even in cases where either would work. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html)

> `to_timestamp` and `to_date` exist to handle input formats that cannot
> be converted by simple casting. For most standard date/time formats,
> simply casting the source string to the required data type works, and
> is much easier. [...]

One or the other may be what you need.
This works:

```
SELECT to_timestamp('129:51', 'MI:SS')::time AS col_overtime

02:09:51
```

But this does not:

```
SELECT cast('00:' || '129:51' AS time) AS col_overtime
```

And when simply casting `'29:51'::time` the minimal format is taken to be `HH24:MI`, not `MI:SS`.

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb/299) (currently dead)

Answer (score 1):

Try prepending `'00:'`:

```
select cast(concat('00:', column_time) as time)
```

Comment: That works, the data in the column now displays as "00:29:51", I know that before I had this working without the leading 00's, I believe I was just doing avg(CAST(column_time AS time)) before. Any other ideas? I could convert the column_time type to something other than varchar if needed.

Comment: @MajorMajor At a guess it worked before because you had minutes values less than 24, so it seemed to work.